# Problem with run-length encoding code

Tags: haskell

This was the #10 of the 99 Haskell questions:

(*) Run-length encoding of a list. Use the result of problem P09 to implement the so-called run-length encoding data compression method. Consecutive duplicates of elements are encoded as lists (N E) where N is the number of duplicates of the element E.

Example in Haskell:
`encode "aaaabccaadeeee"` -> `[(4,'a'),(1,'b'),(2,'c'),(2,'a'),(1,'d'),(4,'e')]`

Here is my code:

```
import Data.List
encode :: [a] -> [(Int,a)]
encode = map (\ws -> (length ws, head ws)) . group
```

Here is the error I got:

```
No instance for (Eq a)
arising from a use of `group'
In the second argument of `(.)', namely `group'
In the expression: map (\ ws -> (length ws, head ws)) . group
In an equation for `encode':
    encode = map (\ ws -> (length ws, head ws)) . group
```

I don't understand what's wrong with the use of group, and if I change the type of function to `String -> [(Int, Char)]`, it will run through.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To use the `group` function, you need to promise that you will pass a list of items on which `==` can be used, which is to say, members of the `Eq` typeclass.  If you omit the type, or you specify a type which is a member of `Eq`, it will work; if you want to be more general, you need to promise it that you are using something that is in `Eq`:

```
encode :: Eq a => [a] -> [(Int,a)]
encode =  map (\ws -> (length ws, head ws)) . group
```

(In reality this is passing the *implementation* of `Eq` for `a` as a hidden parameter, so `group` will know which `(==)` to use; the similarity to function parameters is deliberate.)

Comment: Function group has the type signature Eq a => [[a]] -> [a]. It takes a list of a's and groups them together (to produce a list of list of a's) based on whether the elements are equal or not. To do this type a needs to be an instance of type class Eq.